# Why is my Mongo query not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to return some data from mongodb in a function. The body of the functions looks like this:

```
var name = '';
var ret = this.collection.findOne({"socket_id" : socket_id}).on('success', function(doc) {
    name = doc.name;
    console.log("name inside mongo callback is not empty" + name);
});
console.log("name here is empty" + name);
```

If I log the data in the console, the callback displays the data properly, but if I return form callback, I cannot seem to catch it from where I call the function. I suspect it has something to do with node.js being asynchronous and stuff, but how can I tackle this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for how to call it synchronously ?

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab yep, that would be an option I guess

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab but I am calling it synchronously as I am using monk as the database driver. I mean, it is asynchronous behind the scene I guess, but it should work that way I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it was exactly because I was trying to get a synchronous response to an otherwise asynchronous functions. If you stumble upon this problem, I would refer you to the answer to this question:

[How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

It has all the answers you need on how to perform such an operation